Java DecimalFormat Rounding Bug?
The following code shows that for java.text.DecimalFormat, even though the rounding mode is HALF_EVEN, the rounded output is 1.57 instead of 1.58.
I tested it in both Java 8 and Java 11. Could anyone please help me confirm if this is a bug in Java DecimalFormat?
        Locale locale = new Locale( "en", "US" );
        DecimalFormat currencyFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
        currencyFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        System.out.println(currencyFormat.getRoundingMode()); // --> HALF_EVEN
        System.out.println(currencyFormat.format(1.575)); // --> 1.57

I noticed that System.out.println(currencyFormat.format(1.57501)); // --> 1.58. That makes me think it could be because 1.575 is parsed as 1.574999999999... That's probably the reason why it didn't round up to 1.58

Your hypothesis is correct.

as has often been written on this site, floating point numbers are mostly never indicated to represent currency. Alternative: BigDecimal

and you are correct 1.575 is actually 1.5749999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875 ( print new BigDecimal(1.575) )

I think you can use BigDecimal rounding mode instead of HALF_EVEN. Because HALF_EVEN mode makes it round down.

I'm not sure what you mean by "BigDecimal rounding mode", as BigDecimal supports many different rounding modes. Also HALF_EVEN does not always round down, it only rounds down the value in this question because it's closer to 1.57 than 1.58. See documentation.
